# Uploading picture to database in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, image-uploading

I have created a form where a user can add news, and i want them to be able to upload a picture as well. I have tried too read what other users create a upload form, but cant understand it.
The picture that gets uploaded needs to store the picture path and all the other information in the database that i have created.
Reason for this is that i want to later display the news and picture that the user created, so it can be viewed.
So i need some help, since i don't quite understand how to do this and I am a beginner in laravel. I don't want to use any .js or other scripts since i want to learn these basics first.

My database:

```
class NyhetsmodulTable extends Migration {


    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('news', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->string('message');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('picture_path');
        });
    }
```

My create.plade.php file (not sure if my file form is right):

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'adminpanel.newsmodule.store', 'files' => true)) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form:: label ('title', 'Title: ' )}}
        {{ Form:: text ('title')}}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form:: label ('author', 'Author: ' )}}
        {{ Form:: text ('author')}}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form:: label ('message', 'News: ' )}}
        {{ Form:: textarea ('message') }}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::file('image')}}
    </li>
    <li>

    </li>
    <li>
        {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

My controller, that i dont understand how to set up:

```
public function uploadFile()
{

}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('adminpanel/newsmodule/create',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@uploadFile',
        'as' => 'adminpanel.newsmodule.upload'
    ]
);
```

Comment: You can't (well shouldn't) really embed a form in a form in HTML. If your plan is to use AJAX to upload the file in the background then you may get away with it, as long as the result of the AJAX request's hidden input is part of the outer form, not the inner one, otherwise its contents may not be submitted to the correct place. But yeah, if you're just expecting a form in a form to magically work it won't. HTML just doesn't work that way. Just include the file input in the outer form as you would for a normal input and it'll work (make sure you use `'files' => true` on the outer form though).

Answer (score 0):

Form open tag should be

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'adminpanel.newsmodule.create', 'files' => true)) }}
```

in first line,
there is no need to redeclare form inside form
files should be set true, so it can send files

and to Store image,

```
$news = News::find(1)
$news->image = Input::file('image');
$news->save();
```

since i thougt u just save path,

```
$pathToFile = '/foo/bar/baz.jpg
Image::make(Input::file('image')->save($pathToFile);
$news->picture_path = $pathToFile;
$news->save();
```

Comment: So i should use that in my store function? This is how the function looks now:

 `public function store()
 {
  $input = Input::except(['_token']);
  $v = Validator::make($input, News::$rules);

  if($v->passes())
  {
   News::create($input);

   return Redirect::route('adminpanel.newsmodule.index');
  }
  return Redirect::route('adminpanel.newsmodule.create')
   ->withInput()
   ->withErrors($v)
   ->with('message', 'There were validation errors');
 }`

Comment: @Uhmar Hasan
I figured it out! Thanks for the help!